# error with creating framework

Tags: ios, opencv, terminal, xcode4.2

I try to install opencv on macbook pro following this [instruction](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation)

i have problem when i build OpenCV framework. when i type
`$ python opencv/ios/build_framework.py iOS` 
i got this problem:

```
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed -- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
error: can't exec '/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild' (No such file or directory)
```

I check Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild. I have this folder. But i need to type without "/" in front. What is the problem here?

Answer (score -1):

You need to install cmake

and run again

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/install.html

Comment: Maybe some more explanation would be helpful?